# Why Maven doesn't find ANALYZE-DUPLICATE function?

Tags: maven, duplicates, dependencies

To detect duplicate dependencies, when I start following command

```
mvn dependency:analyze-duplicate
```

Maven return following error's message

```
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'analyze-duplicate' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1 among available goals unpack-dependenci
es, go-offline, copy-dependencies, analyze-dep-mgt, list, purge-local-repository, help, get, build-classpath, sources, analyze-report, analyze, tree,
unpack, resolve, copy, analyze-only, resolve-plugins -> [Help 1]
```

I'm surprise to read in message that version of plugin is `2.1` because, in my POM I have following lines in which you can see that version is 3.1.1

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.company.xsd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tlga-tests</artifactId>
                        <type>xsd</type>
                        <outputDirectory>
                            ${xsd.external.location}
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>

            </configuration>
            <!-- other configurations here -->
        </plugin>
```

I have installed Maven 3.5.4. on my PC.

What is wrong ?

I have added a goal element in my POM like this

```
<goal>analyze-duplicate</goal>
```

But nothing change.

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess you need to configure the plugin version in the pluginManagement section.

Comment: @JF Meier: thanks for your help but I have forgottent that I use more POM files and Maven-Dependency-Plugin is badly (with false version) in PARENT POM ! I have corrected PARENT DOM and starting again MVN command and this is working (I have a result). The <plugin> section is defined in <plugins> delement. I have not find any <pluginManagement> section.